# Dict Manipulation with GPS co-ordinates

Tags: python, dictionary, gps

I have a huge data that has two ids, start and end time and gps coordinates. I am trying to find the frequency, sum, avg, median, max, min, contact duration and also the freq based on GPS co ordinates.

```
004096f41eb8 00904bf131ad 40.0 820219 438869 820219 438869
004096f41eb8 00904bf469bd 40.0 820219 438869 820219 438869
00022d56dffe 00022dcbe817 962.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00306511e9e0 540.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904b21787a 4250.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904b3b845a 1117.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bc3be80 1117.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bcd5f00 4250.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bfebc7c 3737.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
```

The above are the input sample. `col[0]` and `col[1]` are the ids. I can well find the frequency, sum, avg, median, max, min, contact duration when it comes to ids. But when I have to consider both Ids and Gps coordinates I am not able to include this in same code as given below. I need to find the freq of ids those have same gps coordinates.

eg: col[0] col[1] col[3] col[4] col[5] col[6]

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

pairtimelist = defaultdict(list)
pairgpslist = defaultdict(list)

with open('input', 'r') as f, open('output_all', 'w') as o_one, open('output_contact', 'w') as o_two, open('output_gps', 'w') as o_three:
    for numline, line in enumerate((line.split() for line in f), start=1):
        pair = line[0], line[1]
        pairtimelist[pair].append(float(line[2]))
        pairgps = line[0], line[1], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6]
        #pairgpslist[pairgps].append(float(line[2])) 
    for pair in pairtimelist.iterkeys():
        timeavg = np.mean(pairtimelist[pair])
        timemed = np.median(pairtimelist[pair])
        timesum = np.sum(pairtimelist[pair])
        timemax = np.max(pairtimelist[pair])
        timemin = np.min(pairtimelist[pair])
        freq = len(pairtimelist[pair])
    for pairgps in pairgpslist.iterkeys():
        freqgps = len(pairgpslist[pairgps]
    #print pair, pairtimelist[pair]
    o_two.write("%s %s \n" % (pair, pairtimelist[pair]))
    o_one.write("%s %s %s %.2f %.2f %s %s %s \n" % (pair[0], pair[1], freq, timesum, timeavg, timemed, timemax, timemin))
    o_three.write("%s %s \n" % (pair, freqgps))

Error: 
 File "pair_gps.py", line 21
    o_two.write("%s %s \n" % (pair, pairtimelist[pair]))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this error is not seen when all the gps related are commented. Is their any simple way to have all together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone is not interested in helping please don't respond.. But do not flag on 'close' it might not be important to you .. It is really important for me to get any help for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line 19:

```
freqgps = len(pairgpslist[pairgps]
```

You are missing the closing parens for the `len` function.

By the way you can very easily achieve what you are trying to do and in a less error prone way using pandas. It would be something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.read_csv('input.csv')\
  .groupby([0, 1])[2]\
  .agg([np.mean, np.median, np.sum, np.max, np.min])\
  .reset_index()\
  .to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: The closing parens worked .. Thanks again.. I will surely try with pandas.